# Cannot open File or Path in web vscode running by using yarn web in docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

### Install dependences

```
RUN apt install make gcc g++ pkg-config -y
RUN npm install n -g && n 11
RUN npm install -g jshint
RUN apt-get install libx11-dev libxkbfile-dev -y && apt-get install libsecret-1-dev -y
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add - && \
    echo "deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install yarn -y
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y
```

### docker exec -it container_id /bin/bash

```sh
git clone https://github.com/microsoft/vscode.git -b master
cd vscode
yarn
yarn watch
yarn web
```

[yarn web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I71Cj.png)

I can open `localhost:port`,
But I cannot open any File or Path.

[No file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68x44.png)